# pyenv-win The term 'youtube-dl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, pyenv

Try to install the 'youtube-dl' package but dont recognize. I use the latest version of `pyenv-win` with python 3.9.4 version and last pip version.

I think the problem is because the path witch cant find for 'youtube-dl' package but I have already the paths on the environment variables.

Edit:

Steps to reproduce:

1. install the pyenv-win (windows version) (I follow the instructions from the repo)
2. install the python 3.9.4 with pyenv
3. update the pip version to lastest
4. install the youtube-dl `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`
5. run the command youtube-dl in power shell to check if it work but error.

Error:
youtube-dl : The term 'youtube-dl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- youtube-dl
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (youtube-dl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

with next command work perfect `python -m youtube_dl --version 2021.06.06`

Comment: Which OS?  Maybe ask on superuser?

Comment: Does youtube-do work when you use it manually from the command line?

Comment: Show exactly which commands and on which OS you used in an attempt to install `youtube-dl` so that it wil be possible to reproduce.

Comment: @rogerdpack Windows 10

Comment: @AlexYu check the edit

Comment: OK.  I suspect that `youtube-dl` script is provided only for unix-like OSes. But if you installed correctly than it must be possible to run with `python -m youtube_dl`. Other solutions could be: a) using Windows exe: https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html , b) running youtube-dl in WSL